# Logcat not showing error unless Android Studio is in focus

Tags: android, android-studio

Am having this weird issue with Android Studio and am hoping someone has a solution to it.Whenever my app crashes (no matter the cause of the error) I don't see the error message in logcat, except Android Studio is the window in focus on my pc. That is, the emulator and android Studio have to be the only windows open on my pc. I've tried leaving the `Log Level` in `Error` with no difference.